# BackgroundWorker Crashes program

Tags: c#, database, backgroundworker, freeze

Event where runworkerasync is called :

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Length <= 3)
        {
            _ishouldnteventrytoupdate = true;
            return;
        }
        _ishouldnteventrytoupdate = false;

        _updated = false;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

DoWork Function :

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
      //  MessageBox.Show("hallo");
       // if (_ishouldnteventrytoupdate) return;
        //if (_updated) return;


         allArtikels = DatabaseConn.GetAllArtikelsArrayList(false, textBox1.Text);
         //backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100);


    }
```

DatabaseConn is a static class, and this is the function that was called :

```
public static ArrayList GetAllArtikelsArrayList(bool showAll,String naamZoeker = "")
    {
 SetupConnection();
        _objConnection.Open();
        var allArtikels = new ArrayList();

        var  strSql = "SELECT ";
        if (!showAll)
        {
            strSql += "TOP 10";
        }
        strSql+="  HOOFDGROEP.HOOFDGROEP, SUBGROEP.SUBGROEP, Artikels.*" +
                               " FROM (Artikels LEFT JOIN HOOFDGROEP ON Artikels.HOOFDGROEPID = HOOFDGROEP.ID)" +
                               " LEFT JOIN SUBGROEP ON Artikels.SUBGROEPID = SUBGROEP.ID WHERE (ArtikelNaam LIKE  '%' + @ArtikelNaam + '%');";

        var objCommand = new OleDbCommand(strSql, _objConnection);
        objCommand.Parameters.Add("@ArtikelNaam", OleDbType.Char).Value = naamZoeker;

        try
        {
            var objReader = objCommand.ExecuteReader();
            if (objReader != null && objReader.HasRows)
            {
                while (objReader.Read())
                {

                    var objArtikel = new Artikel
                    {

                        SubGroepId = IntDbTester(objReader["SubgroepId"]),
                        HoofdGroepId = IntDbTester(objReader["HoofdgroepId"]),
                        AdviesPrijsIncl = DecimalDbTester(objReader["ArtikelAdviesPrijsIncl"]),
                        AdviesPrijsExcl = DecimalDbTester(objReader["ArtikelAdviesPrijsExcl"]),
                        BtwPercentage = IntDbTester(objReader["ArtikelBtwPercentage"]),
                        Naam = StringDbTester(objReader["ArtikelNaam"]),
                        OldId = StringDbTester(objReader["ArtikelOldId"]),
                        Id = IntDbTester(objReader["ArtikelId"]),
                        Voorraad = DoubleDbTester(objReader["ArtikelVoorraad"])
                    };
                    allArtikels.Add(objArtikel);

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

        _objConnection.Close();
        return allArtikels;
```

IntDbTesters , Stringdbtester etc are functions looking like this:

```
public static int IntDbTester(object s)
    {
        return s == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(s);
    }
```

SetupConnection() looks like this :

```
 private static void SetupConnection()
    {
        const string strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                                     "Data Source='Klanten.accdb';" +
                                     "Persist Security Info=False";
        _objConnection = new OleDbConnection(strConnection);
    }
```

Aside from the catch(which never got called before, so I don't think using backgroundworker suddenly makes it get called) there is not a single UI in the backgroundworker, yet my application freezes for ever when I type more than 3 letters in the textbox.

What could possible have caused this?

EDIT : 
The exception was :

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll Additional information: Deze BackgroundWorker is momenteel bezet en kan niet meerdere taken tegelijk uitvoeren. Roughly translates to the backgorundworker is busy and can't perform multiple tasks at the same time

```
if ((backgroundWorker1 != null) &&!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
```

temporarily fixes this, but I want it to actually cancel the current work and start a new one...

Comment: What .net version are you using?

Comment: A backgroundworker can't run multiple tasks at the same time. There are ways to run multiple occurrences of your work simultaneously, but first: 
Think about what you're planning. Each time you type something into the textbox, You're trying to kick off a thread, which will make a connection, retrieve results and assign the results to the same variable. What happens when more than one thread tries to write to the variable at the same time? Making sql connections inside a thread needs to be handled carefully.

Why not fetch your data ONCE and filter it in memory instead of querying each time?

Comment: @zaitsman .NET Framework 4.5.1 installed with Windows 8.1

Comment: What I hoped for that would happen (maybe a little naive) is that the current backgroundworker gets canceled and it tries again with a newer value to search for

Comment: @MoSlo, Bad idea - what If you have more data than memory

Comment: @MoSlo , zaitsman yes I also think thats a bad idea, since I'm running on about 82k records, so that'd be alot of memory

Comment: @Boyen, why not just do (instead of BackgroundWorker):
`private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Length <= 3)
        {
            _ishouldnteventrytoupdate = true;
            return;
        }
        _ishouldnteventrytoupdate = false;

        _updated = false;
        Task.Run(() => {allArtikels = DatabaseConn.GetAllArtikelsArrayList(false, textBox1.Text);});
    }`

Comment: because if I use a backgroundworker, I can make it report progress , and in those report progress events I can load the panels created by each article one by one

Comment: Did you step through the debugger it will show you where it's crashing?

Comment: `if ((backgroundWorker1 != null) &&!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();` is a temp fix, but how can I actually cancel the current backgroundworker and run a new one?

Comment: I agree storing 82K records in memory is a bad idea (no context was in the post) and there are ways to resolve that. But kicking off a thread on every TextChanged that makes a connection is a good way to overwhelm your database.

Comment: @MoSlo how else would I do this then?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing your app or what you need to do with the output so take from this what you'd like. You need to limit your query; fetch only the columns you need. Connection in GetAllArtikelsArrayList() needs to be closed and disposed even on error. Look at the using clause.
You might prefer the System.Threading.Tasks.Task instead of backgroundWorker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues I can see with your code. However, the biggest problem is the fact you are trying to read a UI component from a non-UI thread i.e.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  //  MessageBox.Show("hallo");
   // if (_ishouldnteventrytoupdate) return;
    //if (_updated) return;


     allArtikels = DatabaseConn.GetAllArtikelsArrayList(false, textBox1.Text);
     //backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100);


}
```

You should pass in your text as you call `RunWorkerAsync`

```
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(textBox1.Text);
...
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     allArtikels = DatabaseConn.GetAllArtikelsArrayList(false, (string)e.Argument);
}
```

---

Now that you have brought to light the exception you were receiving it's obvious that the issue was related to attempting to call `RunWorkerAsync` whilst the worker is busy. In order to effectively stop / restart a worker you need to enable cancellation support. For example

```
private void Search()
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(textBox1.Text);
}
...
backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
backgroundWorker1.Completed += (sender, e) {
    if (e.Cancelled) {
        // restart background worker 
        Search();
    }
};
...
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy) {
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
    } else {
        Search();
    }
}
```

Assuming you are after typeahead type behaviour here, firing off a DB query *per keystroke* isn't a great idea. A better idea is to try predict when the user has finished typing and *then* perform the query - this should result in less trips to the DB which means more efficient use of resources and a better overall UX. A simple, yet effective, way of doing this is to have a timer which you reset each time the user edits the text and only trigger the query if the timer time-out is reached.

---

If you need to fire off a new query without waiting on the previous worker then I recommend you use the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than a `BackgroundWorker`.

```
private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;
...
private void Search()
{
    if (this.cancellationTokenSource != null)
        this.cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();   

    // Create a new cancellation token for the new task.
    this.cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = this.cancellationTokenSource.Token;

    // Start the new task.
    var text = textBox1.Text;
    Task.Run(() => 
    {
        return DatabaseConn.GetAllArtikelsArrayList(false, text); 
    }, cancellationToken)
    .ContinueWith((t) => 
    {
        // do something with t.Result if it wasn't cancelled
    }, cancellationToken, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnCancelled, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: good point , changing textBox1.Text to a const string (for testing purposes) wouldn't even fix it though, so that can't possibly be the crasher

Comment: @Boyen if it's *crashing* then you should have an exception message, can you post it?

Comment: reading the value from textBox1 in the worker won't cause a crash and will work correctly. If you tried assigning a value to the textbox then it would cause a cross-thread error

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: Deze BackgroundWorker is momenteel bezet en kan niet meerdere taken tegelijk uitvoeren.

Roughly translates to the backgorundworker is busy and can't perform multiple tasks at the same time, although in the comments on the main question I noted that `if ((backgroundWorker1 != null) &&!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();`    temporarily fixes this, but the desired result is that it cancels the current dowork and starts a new one

Comment: @Tsukasa you shouldn't attempt to access any sort of UI component from a non-UI thread due to UI components having thread affinity. If you have some documentation to back up your claims I'd be happy to read it.

Comment: @Boyen edit your question and add the exception there ... pls

Comment: @James I agree but that isn't causing his crash right now. See my post. I believe he is calling the worker again while it's already running and because he isn't doing any error handling in the event it will crash the app.

Comment: @WiiMaxx Edited the main question

Comment: @Tsukasa yes, the exception makes that obvious now. My answer was based on the information given (of which the exception was not present). I have updated my answer.

Comment: @James I was looking in this area aswell, but this part bothers me : `if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy) {
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
    } else {
        Search();
    }` this basicly means that it won't search at all with the new text;..

Comment: @Boyen consider using the TPL in that case, you can fire off various tasks without having to wait on the other ones.

Comment: @Boyen I've added an example of how you would use the TPL with cancellation support, you might find it provides better throughput than the `BackgroundWorker` as you wouldn't need to wait for the task to finish.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57922/discussion-between-boyen-and-james).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I believe is causing your crash but without knowing your application workflow it's hard to tell

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text.Length <= 3)
    {
        _ishouldnteventrytoupdate = true;
        return;
    }
    _ishouldnteventrytoupdate = false;

    _updated = false;
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(); //THIS IS YOUR ISSUE
}
```

If your worker is already running and you call RunWorkerAsync again you will cause a crash. Especially since you are not catching or checking to see if the worker is already busy.

Comment: updated the main question, this is indeed the problem, but fixing it raises another question, upvoted regardless

Comment: I would handle this differently. I wouldn't make a SQL call each time a user changes the text.

Comment: How would you handle this then? it's supposed to be some kind of "livesearch"

Answer (score -1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h01xszh2(v=vs.110).aspx

You are not permitted to call

```
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
```

on every textBox1_TextChanged while it will cross your 3 letters limit. The way you should do it is:

```
/// Track number of request you will post to DB. Because it is a bad idea to create many concurrent connections and there is limit in your connection pool.
static const ulong THRESHOLD= 5; // Put your number here.
object syncObjetc = new object();    // Sync all reads/writes to your counter.
volatile ulong counter = 0;

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text.Length <= 3)
    {
        _ishouldnteventrytoupdate = true;
        return;
    }
    _ishouldnteventrytoupdate = false;

    _updated = false;

    lock(syncObjetc){
        if (++counter >= THRESHOLD){
              textBox1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(backgroundWorker1_DoWork), textBox1.Text);
}
```

And

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object state)
{
    String text = (String)state;
    // Please use List<Artikel> as return value.
    allArtikels = DatabaseConn.GetAllArtikelsArrayList(false, text);

    lock(syncObjetc){
        if (--counter < THREASHOLD){
            textbox1.BeginInvoke(compareAndUseResult, new object[]{text, allArtikels});
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
private void compareAndUseResult(String query, List<Artikel> result){
    // There is no any warranty about when we will finish and if some new text was already used. It still an option for optimization for you.
    if (query != textbox1.Text)
    {
        // Result is outdated and we do not need it anymore.
        return;
    }

    // use your result to display!
}
```

Please remember it is just a sketch but it should give you an approach you should follow.
And there is an option to implement it using Task and CancellationToken to reduce amount of useless work in case of outdated query.

Comment: -1 locking is a terrible solution for this type of problem, also there are very few scenarios in which the `volatile` keyword should be used, this most certainly isn't one.

Comment: But you should lock, there is no other way to execute this check for threashold.

Comment: And you must be kidding me, lock is a cheapest solution and much cheaper than new Task creation.

Comment: locking is definitely *not* a cheap solution, it blocks the entire context. I can't comment whether it's cheaper to generate a `lock` vs a `Task` creation, however, they are 2 completely different things and in your example....you do both which is unnecessary. Also, Tasks are generally light to construct because they re-use existing threads from the ThreadPool.

Comment: lock in many cases could be very cheap because if wait time is short it will use spinlock inside and it much cheater even to copy few bytes  via for your cancellation token. An main issue - if text changed you will not search for the new query and will just ignore text change!!!